# Does marking a class as final also make every function final?

Tags: swift

As the title says, I'm wondering if by making a class final, and letting the compiler do it's speed optimisation, I need to also mark functions as final or they become final automatically...

Answer (score 4):

`final` applied to a class makes it not subclassable, so in no case you can override any function or property, because in order to do that you have to create a subclass. So yes, it indirectly applies to all of its members

Comment: I know that from the outside they will look the same as the class can't be subclassed, that's why I'm actually interested in the effect it has on the compiler optimisations...

Comment: In that case I suggest you to post the question in the Apple forum, if you're lucky someone from the dev team can give a precise answer, as I think that's probably an internal detail.

Comment: If you do that, and you get a reply, don't forget to let us know!